# How to pass c++ object pointer from c++ side to java side? long? ByteBuffer? or othe

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, long-integer, bytebuffer

I was writing a program that need use JNI, which has the following steps:

1. Create an object at c++ side
2. Call java side to do something
3. get back the object created in 1

the following is the code that pass long to java:

### long version:

MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass{
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("MyClass");
    }
    public static native void init();

    public static native void testCpp(long buf);
    public static void testJava(long buf){
        testCpp(buf);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        init();
    }
}
```

MyClass.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class MyClass */

#ifndef _Included_MyClass
#define _Included_MyClass
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     MyClass
 * Method:    init
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_init
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

/*
 * Class:     MyClass
 * Method:    testCpp
 * Signature: (J)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_testCpp
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
class MyClass{
public:
    int myInt;
};
#endif
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_init(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz){
    MyClass* myClass=new MyClass();
    myClass->myInt=123;
    long myClass_pointer=(long)myClass;
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(env->FindClass("MyClass"),env->GetStaticMethodID(env->FindClass("MyClass"),"testJava","(J)V"),myClass_pointer);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_testCpp(JNIEnv * env,jclass clazz, jlong addr){
    MyClass* myClass=reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(addr);
    printf("%d\n",myClass->myInt);
    delete myClass;
}
```

but I also find some posts that it can convert the object pointer to ByteBuffer first and then pass to java side:

### ByteBuffer version:

MyClass.java

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
public class MyClass{
    static{
    System.loadLibrary("MyClass");
}
    public static native void init();

    public static native void testCpp(ByteBuffer buf);
    public static void testJava(ByteBuffer buf){
        testCpp(buf);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        init();
    }
}
```

MyClass.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class MyClass */

#ifndef _Included_MyClass
#define _Included_MyClass
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     MyClass
 * Method:    init
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_init
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

/*
 * Class:     MyClass
 * Method:    testCpp
 * Signature: (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_testCpp
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

class MyClass{
public:
    int myInt;
};
#endif
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_init(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz){
    MyClass* myClass;
    myClass->myInt=12345;
    jobject myClass_pointer=env->NewDirectByteBuffer(myClass,sizeof(myClass));
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(env->FindClass("MyClass"),env->GetStaticMethodID(env->FindClass("MyClass"),"testJava","(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V"),myClass_pointer);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_testCpp(JNIEnv * env,jclass clazz, jobject obj){
    MyClass* myClass=(MyClass*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(obj);
    printf("%d\n",myClass->myInt);
    delete myClass;
}
```

I search some posts about how to pass c++ pointer to Java side, seems many of them suggested the solutions about long or ByteBuffer either one only, but rare of them compare between long and ByteBuffer. Also I found some question owners use long and sometimes use ByteBuffer.

Which one is better base on type safe and cross platform? long? ByteBuffer? or other data type?or in other question:when to use long and when to use ByteBuffer?

Comment: Using a `ByteBuffer` should be more robust, as the size of a pointer doesn't matter. A `jlong` is 64 bits in size, so storing the pointer in a `jlong` would fail if we at some point in the future get devices with 128-bit pointers. On the other hand, that might not be something you have to worry too much about right now. Indeed, Google themselves are using `jlongs`s to hold pointers in their Android code (see e.g. `getMediaPlayer` and `setMediaPlayer` in [android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp)).